# Toggle Boolean value based on a triple state filter

Tags: python

I'm having a brain melting time with this. For some reason I thought it would be easier, but I'm struggling with this.

I have an application that a user can config before running based on desired parameters the user wants to test. There are 3 filters that the user can either turn on, turn off, or toggle.

If the user wants a filter on, he will set the filter in the configuration file to *True*. If the user wants it off, he sets it to *False*. If however, the user wishes to run the test with the filter on and than again off, he can set the configuration file to *toggle*

here are examples of filter1, filter2, and filter3 stored in a list.

```
toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", False]
toggle_state = ["toggle", True, "toggle"]
toggle_state = [False, "toggle", True]
toggle_state = [True, False, False]
...
```

Any combination should be available for testing purposes.

I have implemented nested *while loops* to accomplish what I'm attempting to do. However, I have had no real success. I have been able to make it work, with just *toggle* for all three filters.

I stripped out the functions related to my in a simple MUC script below.

```
#####CODE BLOCK 1######
import time

def toggle_filters():
    toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", False]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", True]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", False, "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", True, "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = [False, "toggle", "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = [True, "toggle", "toggle"]

    filter_state = init_filters(toggle_state)

    idx = 2
    complete = 2
    terminate = False

    while True:
        print(f"\t{filter_state[0]:<5}{filter_state[1]:<5}{filter_state[2]:<5}")

        ### do something here with the filters ###

        while True:

            if toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and not filter_state[idx]:
                filter_state[idx] = True
                break
            elif complete < -1:
                terminate = True
                break
            elif toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and idx == len(toggle_state) - 1:
                filter_state[idx] = False
                if complete != 0:
                    filter_state[complete] = False
                complete -= 1
                if complete < 0:
                    idx = 1
                else:
                    idx = complete
                continue
            elif toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and idx != len(toggle_state) - 1:
                if complete == 0 and idx == 0:
                    idx += 1
                idx += 1

        if terminate:
            break


def init_filters(toggle_state):
    """..."""

    filters = []
    for idx in toggle_state:

        if idx == "toggle":
            filters.append(False)
        else:
            filters.append(idx)

    return filters


if __name__ == "__main__":
    toggle_filters()
```

however, when I've attempted to add in static values for the filters, it all goes to hell. I updated the toggle_filter() function to start looking for filters that are not set to toggle.

```
####CODE BLOCK 2####
import time


def toggle_filters():
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", "toggle"]
    toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", False]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", "toggle", True]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", False, "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = ["toggle", True, "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = [False, "toggle", "toggle"]
    # toggle_state = [True, "toggle", "toggle"]

    filter_state = init_filters(toggle_state)

    idx = 2
    complete = 2
    terminate = False

    while True:
        print(f"\t{filter_state[0]:<5}{filter_state[1]:<5}{filter_state[2]:<5}")

        ### do something here with the filters ###

        while True:

            if toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and not filter_state[idx]:
                filter_state[idx] = True
                break
            elif complete < -1:
                terminate = True
                break
            elif toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and idx == len(toggle_state) - 1:
                filter_state[idx] = False
                if complete != 0:
                    filter_state[complete] = False
                complete -= 1
                if complete < 0:
                    idx = 1
                else:
                    idx = complete
                continue
            elif toggle_state[idx] == "toggle" and idx != len(toggle_state) - 1:
                if complete == 0 and idx == 0:
                    idx += 1
                idx += 1
            elif toggle_state[idx] != "toggle" and idx == len(toggle_state) - 1:
                if complete != 0:
                    pass
                complete -= 1
                if complete < 0:
                    idx = 1
                else:
                    idx = complete
                continue
            elif toggle_state[idx] != "toggle" and idx != len(toggle_state) - 1:
                if complete == 2 and idx == 2:
                    complete = 1
                    idx = complete
                if complete == 1 and idx == 1:
                    complete = 0
                    idx = complete
                else:
                    idx -= 1

        if terminate:
            break


def init_filters(toggle_state):
    """..."""

    filters = []
    for idx in toggle_state:

        if idx == "toggle":
            filters.append(False)
        else:
            filters.append(idx)

    return filters


if __name__ == "__main__":
    toggle_filters()
```

Which fails each time, and honestly I imagine I'm approaching this from the wrong direction, just based on the shear number of conditions I have to set. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should be looking at?

UPDATE:

if you take the first block of code, it will run as is. The output will look like a truth table.

```
  0  0  0
  0  0  1
  0  1  0
  0  1  1
  1  0  0
  1  0  1
  1  1  0 
  1  1  1
```

This is when you set the filters to all toggle.

I've updated the second code block as a complete MUC.

here the output looks like this

```
  0  0  0
  0  1  0
  1  1  0
```

however it should look like this

```
  0  0  0
  0  1  0
  1  0  0
  1  1  0
```

depending on which filter you set static, the ouputs are not correct.

Comment: "goes to hell", "fails each time".  What are your expected inputs and expected outputs vs. desired outputs?  Make a [mcve] that can be copied and run *without changes* that shows the problem.

Comment: @MarkTolonen What is the difference between expected output and desired output? Did you mean to ask for the output currently seen?

Comment: You said it fails, what is the good output and what output do you get that failed?  You're second code doesn't run without extra work, but both give me a bunch of numbers.  Explain what the numbers are expected to do.  Nothing "failed".  I just got some numbers.  That also assumes I patched in the 2nd code in the first as you expected.  Give us code that runs without changes.

Comment: hello, I've updated the post. I've added two blocks of code, the first block works if the filters are all set to 'toggle'. the code is usable as is, so you should see the output as well. But I put in an example of what you should get. 

The 2nd block of code, is what I have written to take into account if the user wants a static filter value. I gave an example of the bad result, and what it actually should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the same output with less complication.  `itertools.product` is a function that gives you all the combinations of each state listed.  A `TOGGLE` filter can be zero or one, while a `FALSE` or `TRUE` state only provides a zero or one state, respectively.

Does this manage the states you want?

```py
import itertools

TOGGLE = [0,1]
FALSE = [0]
TRUE = [1]

def toggle_filters(toggle_state):
    for state in itertools.product(*toggle_state):
        print(*state)

toggle_filters([TOGGLE, TOGGLE, TOGGLE])
print()
toggle_filters([TOGGLE, TOGGLE, FALSE])
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1

0 0 0
0 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 0
```

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE!!! I need to spend more time understanding the available functions from tools such as intertools. this works exactly as I need it to work. Thank you!!!